# Issue updating Entity converted from DTO using ModelMapper in Spring Boot Service

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, modelmapper

I am building a Spring Boot Service and trying to use ModelMapper to convert between DTO and Entity, but hitting issues on update.  Here is a simplified example:

```
@Data
public class TeamDto {
    private String name;
    private List<PersonDto> members;
}

@Data
public class PersonDto {
    private String name;
}

@Data
@Entity
public class Team {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    private List<Person> members = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Data
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

public interface TeamRepository extends ListCrudRepository<TeamEntity, Long> {}

@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfig {
    @Bean
    ModelMapper getModelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TeamController {
    private final TeamRepository teamRepository;
    private final ModelMapper mapper;

    @PostMapping("/team")
    public void create(@RequestBody TeamDto team) {
        Team teamEntity = mapper.map(team, Team.class);
        teamRepository.save(teamEntity);
    }

    @PutMapping("/team/{id}")
    public void update(@RequestBody TeamDto team, @PathVariable Long id) {
        Team teamEntity = teamRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(NOT_FOUND));
        mapper.map(team, teamEntity);
        teamRepository.save(teamEntity);
    }
}
```

I am able to create a team, but when I try to update, I get an error saying: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: org.aero.cvr.TeamEntity.members.

I'm not sure how best to address this error.

Comment: I looked at the class of the members list in the Team, and found that after loading from repository, the type was `org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag`, but after updating the Team with the DTO using the ModelMapper, it was replaced with `java.util.ArrayList`.  I'm guessing this is the issue, but not sure how to get around this using the ModelMapper.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution I've come up with is to not use ModelMapper to handle the members list.  Instead, have it skip that field:

```
    @Bean
    ModelMapper getModelMapper() {
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.typeMap(TeamDto.class, TeamEntity.class)
            .addMappings(mp -> mp.skip(TeamEntity::setMembers));
        return mapper;
    }
```

and to handle the field manually, updating the existing list, rather than letting ModelMapper replace it, but still using ModelMapper on the objects in the list:

```
    teamEntity.getMembers().clear();
    teamDto.getMembers().stream().map(dto -> mapper.map(dto, Person.class))
        .forEach(teamEntity.getMembers()::add);
```